# Tikz drawing behind a picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, include

I'm currently learning Latex and I want to create my own title page. 
The purpose is to put a rectangle in the top backgound and place an image above it. But for now, the picture is under and not above the drawing.
So here is what I currently get :
[image]

With the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage{tikz,pgf} %package used for drawing
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main,foreground layer}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=.25]{land.png}\\[2cm]
{\huge \bfseries Test \\[0.8cm]} 
{\large \today}\\[3cm]
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
  \begin{flushleft} \large
    \emph{Author :}\\
    \textsc{Me}\\
  \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
  \begin{flushright} \large
    \emph{Abstract :} \\Some text\end{flushright}
  \vfill
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background layer}
\coordinate (s) at (current page.south);%Bottom of the page
\node [name=colourbar,
anchor=base,
fill=blue!40,
text = white,
minimum width=\paperwidth,
minimum height=5cm] at (s){};
\coordinate (a) at (current page.north);%top of the page
\node [name=colourbar,
anchor=base,
fill=blue!50,
text = white,
minimum width=\paperwidth,
minimum height=10cm] at (a){};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Does anybody knows how to do it? Thx

Answer (score 3):

It could well be that I'm missing something, but to first approximation I'd just change the order:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage{tikz,pgf} %package used for drawing
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main,foreground layer}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background layer}
\coordinate (s) at (current page.south);%Bottom of the page
\node [name=colourbar,
anchor=base,
fill=blue!40,
text = white,
minimum width=\paperwidth,
minimum height=5cm] at (s){};
\coordinate (a) at (current page.north);%top of the page
\node [name=colourbar,
anchor=base,
fill=blue!50,
text = white,
minimum width=\paperwidth,
minimum height=10cm] at (a){};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace*{-3cm}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{land.png}\\[2cm]
{\huge \bfseries Test \\[0.8cm]} 
{\large \today}\\[3cm]
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
  \begin{flushleft} \large
    \emph{Author :}\\
    \textsc{Me}\\
  \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
  \begin{flushright} \large
    \emph{Abstract :} \\Some text\end{flushright}
  \vfill
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just giving you the idea but there will come better answers:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage{tikz,pgf} %package used for drawing
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main,foreground layer}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
  \vspace*{3cm}

{\huge \bfseries Test \\[0.8cm]} 
{\large \today}\\[3cm]
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
  \begin{flushleft} \large
    \emph{Author :}\\
    \textsc{Me}\\
  \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
  \begin{flushright} \large
    \emph{Abstract :} \\Some text\end{flushright}
  \vfill
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background layer}
\coordinate (s) at (current page.south);%Bottom of the page
\node [name=colourbar,
anchor=base,
fill=blue!40,
text = white,
minimum width=\paperwidth,
minimum height=5cm] at (s){};
\coordinate (a) at (current page.north);%top of the page
\node [name=colourbar,
anchor=base,
fill=blue!50,
text = white,
minimum width=\paperwidth,
minimum height=10cm] at (a){};
\node at ([yshift=-4cm]a) {\includegraphics[scale=.25]{example-image-a}};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

I used your includegraphics inside your tikzpicture and after the rectangle inside a node. Nodes in a tikzpicture being created one after previous (in the order that code ask them to be created. So just adding them in the appropriate order will solve your specific problem)

PS: Code can easily become much better... not even pgfonlayer needed... but you can play arround with the idea I gave you and learn much more befor get a better answer.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thx for the reply, I will try it now :)

Comment: Welcome... In my example I used a `\vspace*` command to place the text between the decorating shapes/figures... This is ok for titlepage but if for example you want to change chapter or every page style, you have to search for ways to "change page margins" etc... This way you can change the whole page appearence and the text will be placed between accepted points of the new page... Hope that helps... Happy TeXing